# Create new dynamic dictionary from pandas dataframe

Tags: python

I have a dataframe that I want to take certain values from to enter into a new dictionary. I want to rename some of the columns from the dataframe and make them keys in the dictionary as well. How do I build a dynamic dictionary from scratch entering column values from my dataframe as values into the dictionary?

the df input columns include "AwardNumber" which will be "noticeNumber" in the dictionary and "College" etc. The dataframe looks like this:

```
AwardAmount AwardNumber         College                      Department   Name  Email  
None        3R01GM110382-03S1   College of Arts and Sciences Chemistry    Mary  mary@gsu.edu
```

The desired output would be like this:

```
{ 
    "AwardAmount": None,
    "noticeNumber": "3R01GM110382-03S1",
    "College": "College of Arts and Sciences",
    "Department": "Chemistry",
    "Name": "Mary",
    "Email": "mary@gsu.edu"
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a clearer input and output of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I just updated the question with the desired output. I can put more of the dataframe too if that's helpful! Thanks and sorry-this is my first time posting!

Comment: @kkinatl Your question should be reproducible i.e. post example dataframe and output that you're expecting to get

Comment: Can you please make your example clearer? Why is PersonnelDetails a list? I don't mind if you just call your columns A, B, C, D. Just make sure your inputs and desired output are *consistent* and this will encourage us to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) method. It has `orient` argument, which determines type of dictionary. Since, you didn't provided multiline example, I can only guess what result you want to get. Here is example with `orient="records"`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[None, "3R01GM110382-03S1", "College of Arts and Sciences", "Chemistry", "Mary", "mary@gsu.edu"]], columns=["AwardAmount", "AwardNumber", "College", "Department", "Name", "Email"])
(df.rename(columns={'AwardNumber': 'noticeNumber'})
   .to_dict(orient="records"))
# [{'Department': 'Chemistry', 'Name': 'Mary', 'AwardAmount': None, 'noticeNumber': '3R01GM110382-03S1', 'College': 'College of Arts and Sciences', 'Email': 'mary@gsu.edu'}]
```